# Do i have to await the resolve function when implementing hooks on sveltekit

Tags: java, typescript, sveltekit

i got this handle implementation for sveltekit hooks and because it returns a promise of response, the resolve function doesn't need to be awaited, since it is a function that either returns a value directly or returns a promise of a value, but [this example from the docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#handle) awaits the function. is it ok not to await and when to and not to (if it's ok) await

```js
export const handle:Handle=async ({event,resolve}) => {
    
    let sid = getsid(event.request.headers.get('cookie'))
    event.locals.sessionobj = getSO(sid?sid:'test')

    return resolve(event)
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ok to not await it.

A reason to await it would  be if you want to add extra headers to the response as in the second example:

```js
export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {
  const response = await resolve(event);
  response.headers.set('x-custom-header', 'potato');
 
  return response;
}
```